# Hazelcast dedicated nodes

Tags: java, hazelcast

What is the simplest way to run Hazelcast nodes on dedicated servers?

We have a web application that uses a Hazelcast distributed map.
Currently the Hazelcast nodes are configured to run in the Servlet Container nodes.

As we scale up, we'd like to add dedicated hardware as Hazelcast nodes.

Then we won't need full Hazelcast nodes in the Servlet Containers anymore, those can be clients. (There are licensing costs associated with the Servlet Containers, so getting load off them is good, don't ask...)

So the question is, what's a minimal Hazelcast node installation? Something analogous to a memcached installation.
All it needs to do is read configuration and start up, no local clients.

I see it supports Jetty, but is that needed at all, or is there some simple class in those jars I could execute on a JVM raw?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just create a simple class that calls [HazelCast.init](http://hazelcast.googlecode.com/svn-history/r906/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/Hazelcast.html#init%28com.hazelcast.config.Config%29)

There are a number of test classes in the `com.hazelcast.examples` package which can be run from the bin directory of the hazelcast distribution.

Comment: java -server -cp hazelcast.jar com.hazelcast.examples.StartServer

Comment: I would also add a path to a cluster node specific config (otherwise it'll just use a default one) `java -server -cp hazelcast.jar  -Dhazelcast.config=<path-to-this-node-hazelcast-conf.xml> com.hazelcast.examples.StartServer`

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**

Newer version:

`java -cp hazelcast-3.7.2.jar com.hazelcast.core.server.StartServer`

Older version:

`java -cp hazelcast-2.0.3.jar com.hazelcast.examples.StartServer`

This will start a standalone Hazelcast instance

---

If you're using maven:

`mvn -DgroupId=com.hazelcast -DartifactId=hazelcast -Dversion=3.7.2 dependency:get`

`cd ~/.m2/repository/com/hazelcast/hazelcast/3.7.2`

will get you to the folder with the jar

Answer (score 3):

You can get it to run by calling `{hazelcast-directory}/bin/server.sh`or on Windows `{hazelcast-directory}/bin/server.bat`.

The configuration file can still be found in `{hazelcast-directory}/bin/hazelcast.xml`

This is an update to thSoft's answer as that way is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply run `hazelcast/bin/start.sh` (the configuration file is `hazelcast/bin/hazelcast.xml`).