# Hazelcast as a Linux Service

Tags: linux, hazelcast

I have configured Hazelcast in my application and deployed it in glassfish, and tested it with ome simple methods in a REST service.

Now I want to install it in my servers as a Linux Service, to start running when the servers start, and I want to my glassfish application to be able to recognize this service and read or set variables in my map, using distributed lock.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an init.d script to start `Hazelcast` node and use `HazelcastClient` in your application to connect to `Hazelcast` node.

Look at an answer to a similar question:

[Hazelcast dedicated nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10395372/682580)

And blog post about starting standalone nodes;

[Hazelcast: Starting standalone Hazelcast nodes](http://blog.ilikeplaces.com/2012/05/hazelcast-starting-standalone-hazelcast.html)

To connect `Hazelcast` node using `HazelcastClient` in your app deployed to Glassfish;

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
config.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("localhost");
HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);
Map map = client.getMap("map");
```